# Resume App from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, resume

Is there a way to `Resume` an app from a `BroadcastReceiver`? (in the way that the Launcher Resumes or Starts an app)

I want to do this when the device is plugged in (don't worry, this isn't going in the Play store)

It seems like you must use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` or else you receive a `RuntimeException` for `"Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context"`

```
public class PowerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED")) {

            final Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, FooActivity.class);
            //newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            context.startActivity(newIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: "Resume App from BroadcastReceiver" is the title

Comment: But what do you want to know? Whether you need to set the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag? Yes, you do.

Comment: Starting a new task does not resume the application. It starts a new activity stack.

Comment: The question asks if there is a way to Resume the existing Task

Comment: No, it won't start a new activity stack if there is a task for your activity already. See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) for `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

Comment: I was able to get the `RunningTaskInfo` for the app, and start a new task with the `topActivity` class, but that seems like a hack. The documentation says not to rely on `RunningTaskInfo` being accurate